# Subscribing to an event for the duration of a using block

Tags: c#

I often come across the following code:

```
myService.SomeEvent += listener;
myService.DoSomething();
myService.SomeEvent -= listener;
```

This is great, but it'd be nice if we could do this in a nicer way.  I was thinking of doing something like:

```
using(EventScope.Start(myService.SomeEvent, listener)){
    myService.DoSomething();
}
```

Unfortunately this is prohibited by C# because myService.SomeEvent can only appear on the left hand side of a += or a -= (for good reason).  My question is what other options do I have?  Ideally I'd like this to be type safe, which rules out reflection and doing the following (which I've already implemented):

```
using(EventScope.Start(myService, "SomeEvent", listener){
    myService.DoSomething();
}
```

To be clear I'm not married to using the 'using' syntax, and arguable you could say that it's a perversion of the language.  Other options would be appreciated!

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the best you'll get away with is passing a string and constructing an EventInfo object from that.

Comment: I was hoping that wasn't the case... it works fine, but it's not ideal.

Comment: As a matter of style, I'd use try-finally for this. That emphasizes that the _semantics_ of the operation are "subscribe the event, do the thing, always unsubscribe". Using a disposable object emphasizes "this thing has resources which need to be aggressively cleaned up".  I do not like mixing program semantics with cleanup mechanisms. I don't think I'd go as far as "perversion" but it is at the very least a bad smelling practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a way to do this with cleaner syntax, but if you have a struct like this...

```
public struct ActionDisposable : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Action _action;

    public ActionDisposable(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _action();
    }
}
```

...and a method like this:

```
public static IDisposable EventScope(Action subscribe, Action unsubscribe)
{
    subscribe();
    return new ActionDisposable(unsubscribe);
}
```

That would let you write code like this:

```
using (EventScope(() => myService.SomeEvent += listener, () => myService.SomeEvent -= listener))
{
    myService.DoStuff();
}
```

Or like this:

```
myService.SomeEvent += listener
using (new ActionDisposable(() => myService.SomeEvent -= listener))
{
    myService.DoStuff();
}
```

Comment: Going back and marking answers on some of my old questions.  This is the best of the available answers...

Answer (score 2):

Are you worried that the event won't be unsubscribed because of an exception or something? If so you could use try/finally. Otherwise, I think the original way is best, and looks just fine to me.

Comment: That's exactly the reason why.  I could use try/finally, which is just what a using block is (kind of).

Comment: The using statement suggests IDisposable semantics to me, while the try/finally suggests you're worried about an exception. I'd go with try/finally.